# What do Spain get for winning Euro 2012?

Tags: rules, football, euro, uefa

So Spain, the winners of Euro 2012, now have a UEFA Trophy in their hands and a handful of winners medals for good measure.

But, are there any additional benefits/ prizes of winning the European Cup?

Answer (score 6):

Spain won **€23 million** according to the following calculation:

1. **€8m** fixed for playing in UEFA EURO 2012.
2. **€0.5m** for the draw against Italy.
3. **€1m** for winning the game against Ireland.
4. **€1m** for winning the game against Croatia.
5. **€2m** for participating in the quarter-final against France.
6. **€3m** for participating in the semi-final against Portugal.
7. Finally, **€7.5m** for winning UEFA EURO 2012.

> Participating teams at the UEFA EURO 2012 final tournament will pay
>   the fixed participation contribution fee per team of €8m. Further, a
>   performance bonus at the group stage of €0.5m per draw and €1m per win
>   was fixed, as well as a bonus of €1m to the third-placed team in the
>   group. The quarter-finalists will each receive €2m, the semi-finalists
>   €3m, the runners-up €4.5m and the winners of UEFA EURO 2012 €7.5m.
>   Thus the total amount available for distribution is €196m (up from
>   €184m for UEFA EURO 2008).

[Source](http://www.sport24.co.za/Soccer/Euro2012/Euro-2012-prize-money-list-20120702)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the financial benefits detailed in Dor Cohen's answer, Spain also achieved:

**Fifa World Ranking Points**

Spain will have picked up a considerable number of Fifa World Ranking points by winning this tournament and via the manner in which they did so.  With continental cup tournaments carrying a 3.0x multiplier, Spain will have further cemented their World #1 status.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Rankings#2006_ranking_system_update)

**Record**

This is the first time in history that a team has won 3 back-to-back major tournaments, those being:

- UEFA Euro 2008
- Fifa World Cup 2010
- UEFA Euro 2012

I wouldn't be too surprised if they made it four at the 2014 World Cup.

**Prestige**

All in all, what may matter more than **any** financial or statistical benefit is that the team can say they are the best.